# Mockito - How to inject mocks if superclass contains field with same name and type as child class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is it possible to inject mocks in the superclass fields which are having the same name and type as the child class.

In my situation, I have a controller class

```
abstract class BaseController {
    protected AccessManager accessManager;
}
```

It is extended by a class like below:

```
class ApiController<T> extends BaseController {

}
```

And finally, a more specialized controller extends it like this:

```
class PersonController extends ApiController<Person> {
     private AccessManager accessManager;
}
```

I am writing unit tests for `PersonController` and while testing it, some of its methods call the `BaseController`'s method, which delegates calls it's `protected` member object, which is always `null`.

I have tried using `@InjectMocks` and used `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` to set the protected field of the `BaseController`, but those methods only end up setting the field on `PersonController` class because their names and types are same.

I have spent a lot of time in this but not able to solve it. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: And you can’t change the (suboptimal) design of your controller classes? You can just find all the fields with this name using normal reflection (from each super class) and set it manually.

Comment: I can't change it, because my job is only to write test cases. Design is not my domain

Comment: Show your usage of `ReflectionTestUtils`? There is a `setField` method that takes a "target class"? You should be able to specify the target class as `BaseController.class`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @strelok mentioned you can just use method with following signature

```
public static void setField(@Nullable Object targetObject, @Nullable Class<?> targetClass, @Nullable String name, @Nullable Object value, @Nullable Class<?> type)
```

It requires you to specify which class to use during field setting, e.g. `Parent` or `Child`

```
public class Parent {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void printNames() {
        System.out.println("I'm " + this.name);
        System.out.println("My father is " + super.getName());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(child,Parent.class, "name", "fatah",String.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(child,Child.class, "name", "abdul",String.class);
        child.printNames();
    }
}
```